# I want to disable a "post" button and enable it again once an image has been selected?

Tags: swift, button, uiimage, isenabled, disable

I am trying to disable my post button if the user has not selected a picture to post, so far, I've only managed to disable it if the textfields have not been edited. I also have two buttons, button one: lost, button two: found. The user needs to tap one or the other as well. Is it possible to also disable the post button if neither of these two buttons have been tapped?

Here's my code so far!

```
func handleBlancInformation(){
    address.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    breed.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    phone.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange() {
    guard let address = address.text, !address.isEmpty, let breed = breed.text, !breed.isEmpty, let phone = phone.text, !phone.isEmpty
        else {
        postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            postButton.isEnabled = false
            return
    }
    postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    postButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: show the code for selecting an image

Comment: Buttons are not "selectable" so what exactly are we talking about?

Comment: @objc func handleSelectPhoto() {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: extension PostViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        print("did Finish Picking Media")
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
            imagePosted.image = image
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Comment: hey matt! sorry, tapped. But my question remains, is it possible to disable the button until one of the two buttons is tapped?

Answer (score 0):

```
func handleBlancInformation(){
    address.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    breed.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    phone.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

try this code i have changed addTarget event so it will work :)

Comment: Hey Mahesh! Thanks for the reply. The code i had already worked, but my question was how to also disable the post button until both a picture has been selected, and a button has been tapped? Best regards :)